# python script input check not running script

Tags: python, input

Hey i got email script and it's working on sublime so on, now when i wrote all my 3 scripts in one 2 of them work. Another script where user selects which script  user wants to run Email script itself works without def of course i need def to run it from another and fun thing is that if i delete password then i get error from google can't decode so somehow it runs when i write to input 'email'  i don't get that email if i write another to sublime without def it sends it right away. Everything is imported on top of script on under is the call and for other module def it's exactly same like this one.

```
if ask_user == 'email':
    time.sleep(0.5)
    oscripts.email_script()
```

Like i said without def it works fine now if i type on console which one i want to run 2 of scripts works except this one. Sorry for my bad English any tips?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  I think your writing will be a bit easier to follow if you learn more about where to use commas to separate parts of a sentence and give it a more obvious structure.  Running a sentence together with 'and' and 'but' is less easy to scan quickly.